# Update an article

Tags: joomla, joomla-article

I have multiple websites and have same Company Address.

My problem is. Is it possible to update only the company address of one website and it's automatically update all the company address of multiple websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the websites on the same webspace (because many hosting don't allow external connection), you can write your own script which iterate among all the databases (obviously one for each website) and update the right article in everyone.